# How to find an example for a measure which is not continuous from above?

Tags: measure-theory

I need to give an example of a measure $\mu$ and subsets $A_n$ s.t. $$A_1\supset A_2\supset ...$$ and $$\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)$$

I hat the following in mind. Take $\mu$ to be the counting measure and $A_1=\mathbb{N}, A_2=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\},...$ then $$\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$$
but now I have some strugles to show the other part with the limes. could someone help me please? It would be nice if we could procede with this example since this was my own idea without using any internet.

Comment: Try computing $\mu(A_n)$ for fixed $n$, what does that tell you about the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since $A_n = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\dots , n\}$ has infinitely many elements for any $n$, we must have
$$\mu(A_n) = \infty.$$
Now what can you conclude about $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)$?

Comment: Ah so then we can conclude that the limit is also infinity? Is it correct that the measure is not continuous in general therefore we can‘t take the limit inside?

Comment: Yes, the limit is thus $\infty$. Well, it is true that the measure is not continuous (from above) in general, but the actual reason that we cannot "take the limit inside" is that we have just proved directly that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n) = \infty \neq 0 = \mu (\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n)$.

Comment: ah oh makes sence but if I speak about continuity from below, then I can always take the limit inside right?

Comment: yes. This is proven in most elementary books about measure theory. An important case where we also have continuity from above is when $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ and $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \dots$. But the first requirement is clearly violated in this example.

Comment: yes so we learned this case that it is always true when the measure is finite